# снова ошибка help sos

Tags: python-3.x

```
def konkurs_bal(zno_1=0.4, zno_2=0.3, zno_3=0.2, bal_at=0.1, reg_k=1.02):
    message_1 = int(input("Введіть бал з української мови: "))
    message_2 = int(input("\nВведіть бал з історії України: "))
    message_3 = int(input("\nВведіть бал з математики або іноземної мови: "))
    message_4 = int((input("\nВведіть атестату: "))    
    result = ((message_1 * zno_1) + (message_2 * zno_2) + (message_3 * zno_3) + (message_4 * bal_at)) * reg_k 
    return result
    
rahunok = konkurs_bal(zno_1=0.4, zno_2=0.3, zno_3=0.2, bal_at=0.1, reg_k=1.02)

print(f'\n результат = {rahunok}')
```

---

```
  File "mir.py", line 6
    result = ((message_1 * zno_1) + (message_2 * zno_2) + (message_3 * zno_3) + (message_4 * bal_at)) * reg_k
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Не пойму где ошибка?

Comment: Почитайте [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательно посчитайте скобки в строке

```
message_4 = int((input("\nВведіть атестату: "))
```

там на одну открывающую больше, чем закрывающих.